# ReactJs - Mapping props to state via async function

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component that gets passed as props a list of addresses (str). I would like to geocode them to be able to map on on a map.

My question is, what is the correct way to map props into state with an async call?

What I have so far:

```
async geocodeAddresses() {
   const geocodedAddresses = []
   this.props.strAddresses.map(address => {
       const geocodedAddress = await this.geocodeAddress(address)
       geocodedAddresses.push(geocodedAddress)
 })
   this.setState({geocodedAddresses: geocodedAddresses})

}



async geocodeAddress(address) {
  return Geocode.fromAddress(address) <-- Where Geocode.fromAddress is an API call
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet? Any piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

This is how I would do it.

```js
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      geocodedAddresses: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const geocodedAddresses = [];

    this.props.strAddresses.forEach(address => {
      Geocode.fromAddress(address).then(geocodedAddress => {
        geocodedAddresses.push(geocodedAddress);
      });
    });

    this.setState({ geocodedAddresses });
  }
}
```

If you need to reuse geocodeAddress, you could still do the "then", I think.

Comment: I like your first version. I have one question though. How do I handle this when my this.geocodeAddress(address) return a promise?

Comment: Is there a reason for that function to return a promise? I guess you would have to wrap it in the componentDidMount like I did in my second version.

Comment: No - I am really new to asynchronous code, so I'm probably doing something wrong. geocodeAddress() function has an API call inside it that returns a promise. How could I handle that? (See bottom of the post)

Comment: I edited my answer. You could try that code or adjust it for your  needs.

Comment: I really like your example. Trying to adjust it to my problem I see (Through the react add-in that my component has the correct state (list of geocoded addresses) when I check it through the add-in. In the render() method, however, if I console.log(this.state.geocodedAddresses.length) it prints 0 - I though that the component would re-render on state changes i.e it should print the correct length?